# Execute python code over multiple files in directory and output multiple file to another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python code that takes 2 input files from the Input folder, they are shapefiles but the format is irrelevant to the questions. I process the files and then eventually output a csv file to the Output folder.

To help visualize this maybe the flow line can explain what I do.

```
Input/Lines/line1.shp + Input/Points/point1.shp >> Python Code >> Output/data1.csv
```

I would like to be able to iterate the python code over all the input files in the input folders and store all the output files. So line1.shp+point1.shp = data1.csv and line2.shp+point2.shp = data2.csv and so on..

Any guidance or help on how to do this would be great, the code runs well for any input but would like to be able to do it on a lot of data. I am fairly new to python and don't really know what to look for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a for loop will be helpful as follow:

```
>>> import shapefile
>>> import csv
>>> file_point = 'Input/points/point%s.shp'
>>> file_line = 'Input/Lines/line%s.shp'
>>> file_output = 'Output/data%s.csv'
>>>
>>> number_of_file = 10 # your file size
>>>
>>> for file_index in range(1,number_of_file+1):
...     sf_p = shapefile.Reader(file_point%str(file_index))
...     sf_l = shapefile.Reader(file_line%str(file_index))
...
...     # do some things you want
...
...     with open(file_output%str(file_index), 'w') as csvfile:
...         # write(your data)

# example of file pathes in for loop
Input/points/point1.shp
Input/points/point2.shp
Input/points/point3.shp
Input/points/point4.shp
Input/points/point5.shp
Input/points/point6.shp
Input/points/point7.shp
....
```

And those two websites will be helpful for shapfile and csv reader/writer in python

https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

To start off Im not sure what you need to do with the files, but it seems like you have that covered. There are some parts of the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) that you might find useful. I have include the functions that seem most useful in your case.

```
# os module
import os

# get the current path where your program is executing
current_path = os.getcwd()
# or
current_path = 'my/file/path/to/files'

# lists all the files and directories in the current path
for item in os.listdir(current_path):

    # the file path for each item in current_path
    file_path = current_path+"\\"+item

    # make sure the path is not a directory
    if not os.path.isdir(file_path):

        # separate the file name and file extension
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)

        # make sure you are operating on .shp files 
        if file_extension == '.shp':
            # do you file processing here
            # also create you output files here 
            # if you want 1 output for every input file
```